# .htaccess to partially redirect index requests

Tags: .htaccess, webserver

I'm doing some work for a friend on their website, and while we are working on the new site I would like to set up their .htaccess file to redirect users with the following rules:

- Redirect any requests to / or /index.html to a subdirectory (e.g. both `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/index.html` should redirect to `http://example.com/legacy/index.html`)
- Allow direct requests to index.php to pass through without redirect (e.g. `http://example.com/index.php`)
- If possible, requests to a second subdirectory get redirected to index.php (e.g. `http://example.com/beta/` redirects to `http://example.com/index.php`)

This is probably a simple request, but I have no experience with the rules language that .htaccess uses.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Redirect any requests to `/` or `/index.html` to a subdirectory (e.g. both `http://example.com/` and `http://example.com/index.html` should redirect to `http://example.com/legacy/index.html`)

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(index\.html)?$ /legacy/index.html [L]
  ```
- Allow direct requests to index.php to pass through without redirect (e.g. `http://example.com/index.php`)

  ```
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  ```
- If possible, requests to a second subdirectory get redirected to index.php (e.g. http://example.com/beta/ redirects to `http://example.com/index.php`)

  ```
  RewriteRule ^beta/?$ /index.php [L]
  ```

These would all go in the htaccess file in your document root. If you actually wanted to redirect the browser so that the URL in the address bar changes, include a `R=301` in the square brackets: `[L,R=301]`. If when you say "*requests to a second subdirectory get redirected to index.php*" meaning "any subdirectory", then the rule needs to be changed to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i kind of did the reverse with codeigniter ...

```
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /myproject
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';
    $config['index_page'] = '';
```

hope this helps